# Linking kernel voids without CPU parse (Compute shaders)

Tags: c#, gpu

Is it possible to parse data between compute shader voids without having to create a new buffer and cpu link (Using unity with C# interface).

For example I have a kernel with position data on a set of vector arrays.
I then want to adjust those positions after that kernel has sent them to my shader and rendered.

Edit:
Temporary solution:
Combined all data types to one int and dispatch to one kernal - this is an issue however , as I can't run efficient thread distribution - currently running 512 (1D).

Comment: Perhaps with OpenCL (but I may misunderstand the question)

Comment: Ah I'm working with HLSL on DX11.
Just need to send a vector to another kernal without going through CPU with the RWStructuredbuffer's

Comment: I don't think they're called voids...

Comment: I'm running 5 of them now within seperate kernels.
Others may refer to them as methods -but that's object based terminology. Not HLSL.

Comment: @JamieNicholl-Shelley A function returning void has never in any language known to man been called `void`, much like how you don't refer to a function returning an int as an `int`. Kernel functions in compute are functions, or if you need to indicate the return type, a `function returning void` or colloquially, `void function`.

Comment: Sorry if my shortening of terminology confuses, I assure you it isn't due to a lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research and gaining a greater understanding of GPU architecture (it really helps if you have an electronic/microprocessor studies background here).

Simple answer no: you cannot parse between kernals without CPU managment , which causes bottlenecking...and defeats the purpose of GPU calculations.

However you can run functions external to the main Kernal function as long they return a valid HLSL data type (so no GPU localised structs - use CGING file for that one.)

So thanks again stack exchange for pointing in the right direction : Alcohol.

E.g: 
http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2013/01/12/quick-and-easy-gpu-random-numbers-in-d3d11/